# itk::BinaryFillholeImageFilter does fill the hole in a binary itk::Image

Tags: itk

I have a binary itk image that I am trying to fill the holes using `itk::BinaryFillholeImageFilter`

```
using FillholeFilterType=itk::BinaryFillholeImageFilter<ImageType>;


FillholeFilterType::Pointer fillHoleFilter=FillholeFilterType::New();
fillHoleFilter->SetInput(someFilter->GetOutput()); 
fillHoleFilter->SetForegroundValue(itk::NumericTraits<PixelType>::max());
fillHoleFilter->Update();
```

However, it does not fill the holes. `ImageType` is `float` and its dimension is `3`. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you show us an image from your data so we can see what it looks like?

Comment: @DaveChen I shared [the link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l8n5P7Rl36ghf7fFaLAjZdQnc44pRe0x/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @DaveChen as you can see there are tiny holes that it seems the filter for filling does not work              here.

Answer (score 2):

I ran SimpleITK.BinaryFillhole on your image, setting the foreground value to 1.0.  Basically the same thing you did except the function version of the filter.  It worked as expected.

The BinaryFillhole filter fills in holes that are contained completely within the object.  In your case, there were some tiny, 1 pixel, holes that were filled in.

Maybe you were expecting some of the holes/junk along the object boundary to be filled.  Because those holes are in some way (perhaps very small way) connected to the boundary, the filter does not fill those holes.

Perhaps you could try some smoothing of the image first.

Comment: Thanks. I could see that it could fill the holes, what about bigger holes, it seems it is not filling the bigger holes in [another image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/154faSrBqM8eHMB1yUg9dx1NCEDQtTFsy/view?usp=sharing) . What is the usage of `fillHoleFilter->SetFullyConnected(true);`?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`BinaryFillholeImageFilter` expects a binary image. Convert your image to `itk::Image<unsigned char, 3>` first, and then apply hole filling.

Comment: Thank you, but still no changes after changing the `PixelType` to `unsigned char` :(